# How can I cycle through and display elements from a split string in java?

Tags: java, string, jtextarea

I have to do a project for college that reads in data from an external text file and has a next/previous/exit button to cycle through the various blocks of text. This is my first encounter with gui's and I'm finding displaying items quite difficult. In various iterations I have made the correct blocks of text appear but cannot cycle through them. Now they are not even displaying. I have plenty of time, so if I'm just going the completely wrong way about this, a complete rebuild isn't out of the question and any suggestions are welcome. It compiles fine, but nothing displays in the JTextArea.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{
//Main panels declaration
private JPanel main1;
private JPanel main2;
private JPanel main3;

//Label Declaration
private JLabel topBar;

//Text area declaration
private JTextArea mainText;
int page = 0;

//Buttons declaration
private JButton prev;
private JButton next;
private JButton exit;

String output = "";
String [] hero = output.split("@");


//Constructor
public MainFrame() throws IOException
{   //Declare Layouts
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2,1);
    BorderLayout bor = new BorderLayout(50, 10);
    FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout();

    //Set frame layout
    setLayout(flo);
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);

    //Initialise main panel 1
    main1 = new JPanel();
    main1.setLayout(grid);
    add(main1);
    main1.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());


    //Initialise main panel 2
    main2 = new JPanel();
    main2.setLayout(bor);
    main1.add(main2);


    //Text area
    mainText = new JTextArea(20,50);
    JScrollPane JSP = new JScrollPane(mainText);
    main2.add(bor.CENTER,mainText);
    mainText.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());
    mainText.setEditable(false);
    mainText.setText(hero[page]);

    //File Handling
    File inputFile = new File ("ProjectInputFile.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);


    while(scanner.hasNextLine())
    {
        output = output + (scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
    }

    //Top Bar
    topBar = new JLabel("Hero Viewer", SwingConstants.CENTER);
    main2.add(topBar, bor.PAGE_START);

    //Initialise main panel 3
    main3 = new JPanel();
    main3.setLayout(flo);
    main1.add(main3);

    //Prev Button
    prev = new JButton("Prev");
    main3.add(prev);
    ActionListener PrevList = new PrevButton(); //Call Button Listener
    prev.addActionListener(PrevList);

    //Exit Button
    exit = new JButton("Exit!");
    main3.add(exit);
    ActionListener ExitList = new ExitButton(); //Call Button Listener
    exit.addActionListener(ExitList);

    //Next Button
    next = new JButton("Next");
    main3.add(next);
    ActionListener NextList = new NextButton(); //Call Button Listener
    next.addActionListener(NextList);
}

//Prev button event listener
public class PrevButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        page = page --;
        mainText.setText(hero[page]);

    }
}

//Exit button event listener
public class ExitButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        setVisible(false);
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

//Next button event listener
public class NextButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        page++;
        mainText.setText(hero[page]);
    }
}

//Main Method
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    MainFrame MF = new MainFrame();
}

}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: In the java console? Nothing until i hit the next button more than once, then I get an 'array out of bounds' error, but at the moment there is only enough data for the 0 and 1 array spaces, so that's to be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    output = output + (scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
}
```

Try adding

```
hero = output.split("@");
```

I doubt if your hero array is empty.

Comment: Thanks! It works but still doesn't display the first item until I hit 'next' and then 'prev' to go back to the first item. One question... why did it work? Does that line assign all separate strings to the array? I thought 'String [] hero = output.split("@");' did that anyway?

Comment: Add mainText.setText(hero[page]);page++ after hero = output.split("@") . It is because you are creating the hero array before you acrtully read the file. So now output is "". So split will be empty. Same is the reason why first time is not displayed

Comment: You will still get the arrayoutofbounds exception if you click several times. This is because your page variable is increasing more than the size of the array. You might have to do page = page%size to solve this problem. I belive you can figure out where you have to put it.

Comment: Oh OK! :D Thanks a million! I would upvote you but my score is too low :(

Comment: its ok ;) accpet the answer  :P